# Getting error message compiling android project

Tags: java, android

I'm going through this tutorial from droid draw:
http://www.droiddraw.org/tutorial3.html

I'm getting this error when I try to compile the code in eclipse:

```
[2011-05-18 20:09:23 - DroidDrawTutorial1] /home/ollie/workspace/DroidDrawTutorial1/res/layout/main.xml:8: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'entries' with value '@arrays/items').
```

Here are the contents of res/layout/main.xml:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout
android:id="@+id/widget29"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<ListView
android:id="@+id/widget30"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:entries="@arrays/items"
android:layout_x="0px"
android:layout_y="2px"
>
</ListView>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Here are the contents of res/values/arrays.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>
<string-array name="items">
<item>item1</item>
<item>item2</item>
<item>item3</item>
</string-array>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try instead

```
android:entries="@array/items"
```

It corresponds to `R.array.items`. The array resources are always called by its resource name, independent of the filename of the xml that defines it:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#StringArray

> String Array
>
> An array of strings that can be referenced from the application.
>
> Note: A string array is a simple resource that is referenced using the value provided in the name attribute (**not the name of the XML file**). As such, you can combine string array resources with other simple resources in the one XML file, under one  element.

Comment: The text in the tutorial is inconsistent. I think the @arrays just needs to match the name of the file; which in my case is arrays.xml.

Comment: You are indeed correct - that's what I get for relying on my intuition. Thanks for your help.

Comment: No, if you took it from a tutorial, it must be a typo in there. The filename is not relevant. See my updated answer. Edit: sometimes the docs help ;)